# Prevent too-tall tables overflowing upwards in top-aligned Beamer frames

Tags: tables, beamer, vertical-alignment, overflow

Even if I use the class option `t` in a Beamer presentation, tables that are too tall do not only overflow downwards but also a little bit upwards. Is there some way to ensure that too-tall tables only overflow downwards?

[image]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{table}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
      \begin{tabular}{@{} r @{}}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        3 \\
        4 \\
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{table}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
      \begin{tabular}{@{} r @{}}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        3 \\
        4 \\
        5 \\
        6 \\
        7 \\
        8 \\
        9 \\
        10 \\
        11 \\
        12 \\
        13 \\
        14 \\
        15 \\
        16 \\
        17 \\
        18 \\
        19 \\
        20 \\
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @FredrikP - Your posting currently reads like you are very concerned about the ever so minor upward shift of the caption in case the table is too tall, yet are simultaneously pretty much unconcerned about much more severe and glaring problem, *viz.*, the table's overflow at the bottom of the frame. Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico The much more severe and glaring problem is only there to illustrate the ever so minor upward shift of the caption. The use case would not have such blatantly overflowing content. Perhaps I should have posted a slightly shorter table as the problem—just like Simon points out in his answer—is still there with shorter tables. The question is ONLY about positioning and not about fitting too much in a too small frame—I do understand that that is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank for your feedback. I found a better solutions that does not requires changes of the content of the document. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, in your MWE the problem disappears when in the second table there are only 14 rows.
Adding # 15 the table **does not overflow** but everything moves up.

**UPDATE**

To solve the issue the  environment `table` was redefined, replacing  `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` by `\centering`.

No change is needed to the content of the beamer document.

[image: zz]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

% *************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter

\renewenvironment{table}[1][]{%
    \def\@captype{table}%
    \par\nobreak\centering} % before \par\nobreak\begin{center}\nobreak}
    {\par\nobreak} % before  {\par\nobreak\end{center}\nobreak}

\makeatother
% ***************************

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{table}[t]
            \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
            \begin{tabular}{@{} r @{}}
                1 \\
                2 \\
                3 \\
                4 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Test}
    
        \begin{table}
            \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
            \begin{tabular}{@{} r @{}}
                1 \\
                2 \\
                3 \\
                4 \\
                5 \\
                6 \\
                7 \\
                8 \\
                9 \\
                10 \\
                11 \\
                12 \\
                13 \\
                14 \\
                15 \\
                16 \\
                17 \\
                18 \\
                19 \\
                20 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Note**

The beamer environment `figure` it is defined in a equal way.

So the same problem will manifest itself with a large figure, but not overflowing: the title will scroll up.

A similar solution will realign the subtitles.

[image: fx]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=blue}

% *************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter

%\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{% original in beamerbaselocalstructure.sty
%   \def\@captype{figure}%
%   \par\nobreak\begin{center}\nobreak}
%   {\par\nobreak\end{center}}

\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{% new definition
    \def\@captype{figure}%
    \par\nobreak\centering} 
    {\par\nobreak}

\makeatother
% ***************************

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test figure I}

    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
        \includegraphics[height= 100pt]{example-image}
    \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Test figure II}
                
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
        \includegraphics[height= 198pt]{example-image}
    \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that I have had a hard time drawing attention on the actual issue. Your solution manages to fix positioning for the two versions that you post. But ideally I would prefer not having to mess with the code for the table that works and the short tables in my question (without minipage) and in your answer (with minipage) don't line up. Do you have any suggestion for how this might be achieved?

Comment: @Fredrik P I found a better way. See the updated answer