# Why don't overflowing tables respect Beamer's t class option?

Tags: tables, beamer, vertical-alignment, overflow

If I use Beamer's `t` class option, then frames should be aligned top and overflowing content should continue downwards without affecting the position of the topmost content. But when it is tables overflowing, then Beamer suddenly partly ignores the `t` class option and lets content jump up. What causes this behavior? And is there some more fundamental way to fix it rather than just adjusting the frame markup?

In the MWE below, it is clear that the table jumps when the 15th line is added whereas the lorem ipsum paragraphs do not jump. I would like all content to behave as the paragraphs. As the behavior is also present with lists, although more gradually, I suspect that it [actually **might** be glue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602681/prevent-too-tall-tables-overflowing-upwards-in-top-aligned-beamer-frames) in the vertical space before the table that is playing tricks with me.

(Note that I am not asking for ways to fit this boilerplate content into the frame by some fancy means such as shrinking it or dividing over separate frames. Too-tall content **should** overflow, but I would very much like for the `t` class option to be respected when this happens.)

[image: Animated version of MWE]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Test}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Test}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{table}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
      \begin{tabular}{@{} r @{}}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        3 \\
        4 \\
        5 \\
        6 \\
        7 \\
        8 \\
        9 \\
        10 \\
        11 \\
        12 \\
        13 \\
        14 \\
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{table}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
      \begin{tabular}{@{} r @{}}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        3 \\
        4 \\
        5 \\
        6 \\
        7 \\
        8 \\
        9 \\
        10 \\
        11 \\
        12 \\
        13 \\
        14 \\
        15 \\
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the table environment by the beamer class uses `\begin{center}`  ... `\end{center}` to center the  caption and the tabular.  The center environment adds vertical space because it's implemented as a list environment (and also calls  `\centering`).

```
\def\center{\trivlist \centering\item\relax}
\def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}
```

Redefining the table environment using only `\centering` fixes the problem.

The same happens with the figure environment. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/602685/161015

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

% *************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
    \renewenvironment{table}[1][]{%
        \def\@captype{table}%
        \par\nobreak\centering} % before \par\nobreak\begin{center}\nobreak}
        {\par\nobreak} % before  {\par\nobreak\end{center}\nobreak}
\makeatother
% ***************************


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{table}
            \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
            \begin{tabular}{@{} r @{}}
                1 \\
                2 \\
                3 \\
                4 \\
                5 \\
                6 \\
                7 \\
                8 \\
                9 \\
                10 \\
                11 \\
                12 \\
                13 \\
                14 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{table}
            \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
            \begin{tabular}{@{} r @{}}
                1 \\
                2 \\
                3 \\
                4 \\
                5 \\
                6 \\
                7 \\
                8 \\
                9 \\
                10 \\
                11 \\
                12 \\
                13 \\
                14 \\
                15 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: b]