# Getting rid of magic number when aligning tables and threeparttables in beamer

Tags: tables, threeparttable, vertical-spacing

I've been trying to make regular tables and `threeparttables` line up in beamer [for](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603124/beamer-why-is-spacing-around-caption-different-with-without-threeparttable) [a](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602903/what-causes-extra-vertical-space-around-caption-with-threeparttable-and-how-to-r) [while](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602699/why-dont-overflowing-tables-respect-beamers-t-class-option) [now](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602681/prevent-too-tall-tables-overflowing-upwards-in-top-aligned-beamer-frames). And I have been making progress: in the below MWE, the tables line up perfectly. But there is still a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) that I haven't been able to get rid of---the annoying `4.30003pt`, which unfortunately needs to change with the document font size. Can you help me figure out where it comes from and if there is some saved length holding the value that I could use instead of just hardwiring it. In the log file, `4.30003pt` shows up under the heading `Completed box being shipped out [1]`---that is the frame with the regular frame---on the line `......\glue(\baselineskip) 4.30003`, which I unfortunately cannot decipher :(

```
\documentclass[10pt, t]{beamer}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}[1][]{%Redefine table environment as per https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603004/71332
  \def\@captype{table}%
  \par\nobreak\centering\vspace{0.45\baselineskip}}
  {\par\nobreak}
\makeatother
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false,
            position=above]{caption}% Format captions for figures and tables
\newlength{\generalcaptionskip}
\setlength{\generalcaptionskip}{\dimexpr\abovecaptionskip-\parskip\relax}
\newlength{\TPTcaptionskip}
\setlength{\TPTcaptionskip}{\abovecaptionskip}
\captionsetup{skip=\generalcaptionskip}
\captionsetup[threeparttable]{skip=\TPTcaptionskip}
\newlength{\TPTpreskip}
\setlength{\TPTpreskip}{\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip+4.30003pt\relax}
\AtBeginEnvironment{threeparttable}{\vspace{\TPTpreskip}}%Move threeparttables up to align with regular tables
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[para, flushleft]{threeparttable}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{table}
    \begin{table}
      \caption{A table}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} Xrrrrr @{}}
        \toprule
        & A & B & C & D & E \tabularnewline
        \midrule
        A somewhat longish row heading & 12 & 34 & 56 & 78 & 90 \tabularnewline
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{threeparttable}
    \begin{table}
      \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{A table}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} Xrrrrr @{}}
          \toprule
          & A & B & C & D & E \tabularnewline
          \midrule
          A somewhat longish row heading & 12 & 34 & 56 & 78 & 90 \tabularnewline
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \begin{tablenotes}
          \emph{Note:} Something noteworthy.
        \end{tablenotes}
      \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with my new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass[10pt,t]{beamer}

\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false,
            position=above]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\SetTblrTemplate{head}{empty}
\SetTblrTemplate{note}{inline}
\SetTblrOuter[talltblr]{headsep=0pt}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{short table}
    \begin{table}
      \caption{A table}
      \begin{tblr}{@{}Xrrrrr@{}}
        \toprule
        & A & B & C & D & E \\
        \midrule
        A somewhat longish row heading & 12 & 34 & 56 & 78 & 90 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{tall table}
    \begin{table}
      \caption{A table}
      \begin{talltblr}[
        note{a} = {First Footnote.},
        note{b} = {Second Footnote.},
        remark{Note} = {Something noteworthy.},
      ]{@{}Xrrrrr@{}}
        \toprule
        & A\TblrNote{a} & B & C & D & E \\
        \midrule
        A somewhat longish row heading\TblrNote{b} & 12 & 34 & 56 & 78 & 90 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks very interesting! Will try it tonight. Is there by any chance some way to replicate `threeparttable`'s `para` option, where the footer items come one after another without line breaks? I can't find anything on it in the documentation.

Comment: @FredrikP I have updated my answer, adding some inline footnotes.